# azure kql to get OSversion and OSName from VMSS

Tags: azure, kql, azure-resource-graph

```
resources
 | where type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachinescalesets"
 | extend
extensions = properties.virtualMachineProfile.extensionProfile.extensions,
osName = properties.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.osDisk.osName,
osVersion = properties.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.osDisk.osVersion,
osType = properties.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.osDisk.osType
```

I can get osType which "Linux" but
I want OSName (like ubuntu, Redhut)
osVersion( like version 18, 19)
what I need to do to get that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resources
|   where   type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachinescalesets"
|   extend  publisher   = properties.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.imageReference.publisher
           ,version     = properties.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.imageReference.version
           ,sku         = properties.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.imageReference.sku
           ,offer       = properties.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.imageReference.offer
```

P.S.

Here is a "tool" that you might find useful:

```
resources
| where type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachinescalesets"
| where * has "ubuntu"
```